# XSLT - why the result of 3 different "value-of select' with 3 different xpath's give me the output in the same line?

Tags: xslt, xhtml

So i have this .xsl file and with 3 different "xsl:value-of select" with different xpath give me in the same line even with break lines trying to separate them.

xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:value-of select="//Utilizador[@id= 'u_03' ]/Username"/><br/>

                <xsl:value-of select="count(//Video[contains(@uti_id, 'u_03')])"/><br/>

                <xsl:value-of select="count(//Comentario[contains(@uti_id, 'u_03')])"/><br/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output .xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
<head>
<title/>
</head>
<body>carlitos<br/>3<br/>0<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `br` element will be rendered as line break by your browser, when you view the resulting HTML code. Thee are no line breaks in the HTML code itself, because inserting them would modify the text nodes surrounding the  `br` elements.  If you really want them, you will have to ask for them explicitly by adding newline character/s as literal text.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i tried to use "<xsl:text>&nl;</xsl:text>" but when i check on the browser it still shows all in one line.

New code output .xhtml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
<head>
<title>hey</title>
</head>
<body>carlitos
3
0</body>
</html>`

Comment: Try `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` (Unix) or `<xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>` (Mac) or `<xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>` (Windows).

Comment: @michael.hor257k still nothing

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of the XML input and the exact code you expect to get as the result.

Comment: You don't really want to be creating HTML that has text as a direct child of the `body` element anyway. Although the browser will probably do something with it, it's not good HTML and isn't going to play well with CSS etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `<xsl:output method="html"/>` to create text/html output. If you wanted to create XHTML then you could use output method="xml", but then you would also need the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` for the result elements, otherwise a browser will not recognize any HTML.